# C# HTTP Basic Authentication credentials being sent too early

Tags: c#, rest, basic-authentication

I'm trying to log in to a server (REST API) which uses HTTP Basic Authentication. The request looks like this:

```
public JObject PerformLogin(string username, string password)
{
    string html = string.Empty;

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(auth_url_internal);
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    //request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;

    string authInfo = username + ":" + password;
    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    JObject jresponse = JObject.Parse(html);

    sess_url_internal = jresponse["internalUrl"].ToString();
    sess_url_public = jresponse["publicUrl"].ToString();

    return jresponse;
}
```

which basically works, however the credentials are being sent too early.

First I used curl to see what the traffic looks like in detail and found a "Location:"-Header, which means that there is a redirect happening. In detail, the server redirects me from `/api/rest/authenticate?version=1.0`, which is the authentication URL (lets call it URL1), to `/authenticationbasic/login?AlcApplicationUrl=/api/rest/authenticate%3fversion=1.0` (URL2).

However, Chrome sends the Credentials to URL2, where my program sends them to URL1 which is too early, because the server expects them at URL2, where my application doesn't send any and therefore gets a false return.

How can i change that behaviour?

Comment: Set this to false `request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` and do your own redirection.

Comment: How can I "do my own redirection"? So basically waiting for the respose, searching for a `Location` header and if present, do another response to that location?

Comment: Yup... you got it...:=)

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try that :)

Comment: I've come across another problem:
When I send the request to URL1 it returns 401 which leads to an exception and no response being read. How can i deal with that?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized. You need probably use the same credential for URL1 and URL2. https://httpstatuses.com/401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the kind help of [x...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6522773/x) I figured out how to do it:

After the `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` simply add

```
if ((int)response.StatusCode == 302) // redirect
{
    /*
        Call the function recursively with the new URL, found in
        response.Headers["Location"], in my case this would be:
    */

    auth_url_internal = response.Headers["Location"];
    return PerformLogin(username, password);
}
```